# Can i enable USB tethering with SL4A?

Tags: android, sl4a

I have had searched in [API reference](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/ApiReference) for a class/method to enable USB tethering, but found none. I wonder if it's still possible.

For information, I use a rooted HTC Wildfire with Cyanogenmod 7 and Android 2.3.7.

If it's not possible, I'm interested for a Java sample code to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Not using the built in APIs (as you've checked), which simply means no, not if you're not willing to do a bit of work.

If, however, you are using Beanshell, JRuby or Rhino, then as per the [SL4A FAQ ("API bridge?" question)](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/FAQ#Is_this_a_complete_API_bridge,_or_are_there_restrictions?), *"you can invoke Java calls directly"* suggesting to *"See the documentation for those interpreters"* for how to do so (though I couldn't find it). However on the [Unofficial Releases](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/Unofficial) page, it states that:

> "Beanshell and Rhino can both directly access the android api.
>   However, many Android api calls required a context, which, due to the
>   way they are run, these interpreters don't have. A solution is being
>   sought... suggestions appreciated."

And as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7049074/584026), I believe a `Context` is required, though I may be wrong.

Finally, your last option would be to [clone the source](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/source/checkout) code for whatever interpreter you're using and add the call(s) your require. Quoting the FAQ again; *"The RPC layer is easy to extend."* and there's even a [little walkthrough](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-scripting/hlUxn852nEw/0pzKD5zN6wIJ) for it.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you have root enabled, you by just try to do it whithoug SL4A or Android. I use this script:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
iptables -D droidwall-3g -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j RETURN
iptables -I droidwall-3g -m owner --uid-owner 0 -j RETURN
iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o rmnet0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o rmnet0 -j MASQUERADE
echo 1 > /sys/class/usb_composite/rndis/enable
ifconfig usb0 192.168.42.129 up
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/usb0/forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/rmnet0/forwarding
```

Maybe for other devices (mine is SE Xperia X10) you need to adjust things like `/sys/class/usb_composite/rndis/enable`.

Comment: How you disable ? You flush the whole stuff ?

Comment: Disabling? Usually I just start similar script to switch USB to storage mode (also behind the Android's back). iptables rules usually just sits around forever (note the "-D" commands to prevent rules piping up which you use script multiple times). To block access to network from USB you can set to "0" any of values (rndid/enable, rmnet0/forwarding, usb0/forwarding). If you don't have iptables you can start some SOCKS or whatever proxy on the device.