# What's the meaning of new @SystemApi annotation, any difference from @hide?

Tags: android, annotations

Android introduced @SystemApi in its SDK source code recently. Seems like same in effect as the @hide annotation before, since they also got stripped from SDK jar classes.

Is there any chance an app can call them in ways different from the old @hide APIs.

```
/**
 * Indicates an API is exposed for use by bundled system applications.
 * <p>
 * These APIs are not guaranteed to remain consistent release-to-release,
 * and are not for use by apps linking against the Android SDK.
 * </p><p>
 * This annotation should only appear on API that is already marked <pre>@hide</pre>.
 * </p>
 *
 * @hide
 */
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Methods annotated with @SystemApi are a subset of ones with @hide.
It's apparently an indicator for internal teams (perhaps also partners) that these methods are actual APIs, although not for public developers.

As a result, @SystemApi methods will be more stable than @hide ones, which could be changed at any time in the future without any compatibility consideration, and also any OEM is allowed to change them at their own will.

If you are trying to invoke internal APIs via reflection, always prefer @SystemApi methods for better future compatibility.

Comment: Is there any way to call functions with @SystemApi annotation?

Answer (score 31):

## `@SystemApi`, `@PrivateApi` and `@hide`

According to [this commit](https://cs.android.com/android/_/android/platform/frameworks/base/+/d5a5b5a547462f3e7c6315a501909bce2418ba86), `@SystemApi` is a rename of the old `@PrivateApi`. APIs marked `@hide` are not necessarily `@SystemApi`, but `@SystemApi` requires `@hide`.

For more information about `@hide` javadoc annotation, [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035271/what-does-hide-mean-in-the-android-source-code) gives a good answer.

Based on my own experiments, **one (non-system application) can still access `@hide` APIs and fields** using Java reflection like (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048922/android-2-3-wifi-hotspot-api)):

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
config.SSID = "AccessPointSSID";

Method method = manager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
method.invoke(manager, config, true);
```

But **trying to access `@SystemApi` things** using Java reflection **is impossible** (following code will trigger [`invocationTargetException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html)):

```
WifiManager manager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

Method method = manager.getClass().getMethod("getPrivilegedConfiguredNetworks");
List<WifiConfiguration> configs = (List<WifiConfiguration>)method.invoke(manager);
```

## P.S.

In the [`WifiManager` java code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.java), the `setWifiApEnabled` and `getPrivilegedConfiguredNetworks` APIs are defined as:

```
/**
 * Start AccessPoint mode with the specified
 * configuration. If the radio is already running in
 * AP mode, update the new configuration
 * Note that starting in access point mode disables station
 * mode operation
 * @param wifiConfig SSID, security and channel details as
 *        part of WifiConfiguration
 * @return {@code true} if the operation succeeds, {@code false} otherwise
 *
 * @hide Dont open up yet
 */
public boolean setWifiApEnabled(WifiConfiguration wifiConfig, boolean enabled) {
    try {
        mService.setWifiApEnabled(wifiConfig, enabled);
        return true;
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and

```
/** @hide */
@SystemApi
public List<WifiConfiguration> getPrivilegedConfiguredNetworks() {
    try {
        return mService.getPrivilegedConfiguredNetworks();
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! In my tests, most APIs with `@SystemApi` and `@hide` annotated (previously only annotated by `@hide`) are still accessible via reflection. What's the detailed message of `InvocationTargetException` in your case?

Comment: I did the experiment on my Nexus 5 with Android 5.0. @oasis-feng I guess the behavior of `@SystemApi` is version related?

Comment: I also tested it on Nexus 5 with Android 5.0.2. Maybe it's different from API to API. Can you paste the detailed message of your InvocationTargetException?