# Not able to import a android.os.SystemProperties

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile-development

I had cloned a project from the Github and in one of its file, the project uses the SystemProperties.java class from the android.os package. But the import line is throwing an error with the following message

`cannot find symbol symbol  : class SystemProperties location: package android.os import android.os.SystemProperties;`

My friends those are working with the same project dont have this error and the Android Studio version, SDK version and everything is same when we compared. Why I am having this error. I opened the SystemProperties file as well in the android.os package but while importing when I type android.os. then the drop down is not showing the SystemProperties file in it. Why is it so ?

I tries to find about it in the internet but the alternate option to use SystemProperties is by using reflection method it mentioned. But I can't write the implementation of reflection for the entire project. I suppose there is something issue in the setup.

Comment: Have you tried building the project? Does the build fail?

Comment: `android.os.SystemProperties` is not a public class of the Android API. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2641111/150978

Comment: The SystemProperties class is marked with @SystemApi annotation. You can read about what it means here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752656/whats-the-meaning-of-new-systemapi-annotation-any-difference-from-hide

Comment: Code is buiding without any problem. Only throwig error when I click on run button.

Comment: In the internet I got only one suggestion and that is Reflect. But for this error I cant write reflection for all such cases, it would be really difiicult to write. I hope the problem might be in SDK or NDK versions. If nothing works fine I can uninstall the application and delete all related files and download its bday first.